# "Fatal error: Index out of range" while working with byte array in swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following code like this,

```
extension Collection {
func element(at index: Index) -> Element? {
return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
}
}

class Example: UIViewController{
          ......

viewDidLoad(){..}
viewDidDisappear(){..}

func readandsend(){
let ReceiveData = rxCharacteristic?.value
        if let ReceiveData = ReceiveData {
            let ReceivedNoOfBytes = ReceiveData.count
            myByteArray = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
            (ReceiveData as NSData).getBytes(&myByteArray, length: ReceivedNoOfBytes)
            print("Data Received ",myByteArray)
               }
```

//Now I'm storing all my bytearray data here

```
var first = myByteArray[0]
var sec = myByteArray[1]
var third = myByteArray[2]
var fourth = myByteArray[3]
```

//Here I'm trying to get past out of range using extension block shown above

```
if let b1 = myByteArray.element(at: 0){
one = myByteArray[0]
}
if let b2 = myByteArray.element(at: 1){
two = myByteArray[1]
}
if let b3 = myByteArray.element(at: 2){
three = myByteArray[2]
}
if let b4 = myByteArray.element(at: 3){
four = myByteArray[3]
}
```

//I have two textbox's from which I need to get the strings and convert to UInt8

```
var tb1 = textbox1.text
var b1 = tb1.flatMap{UInt8(String($0))}

var tb2 = textbox2.text
var b2 = tb2.flatMap{UInt8(String($0))}
```

//Now when I try sending my completed byte array

```
 let completedArray = [UInt8]()

 completedArray[0] = b1
 completedArray[1] = b2
 completedArray[2] = myByteArray[2]
 completedArray[3] = myByteArray[3]
```

//Writing back to peripheral

```
let TransmitData = NSData(bytes: completedArray, length: completedArray.count)

peripheral.writeValue....so on
```

When I send it I'm getting an index out of range error, but have I properly used the extension block? Can someone pls help?

Comment: At which line you are getting this error?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni hi dharmesh kheni I'm getting an error like this symbol stub for: generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, swift.UInt8> of swift.Array.subscript.nativePinningMutableAddressor : (Swift.Int) -> A

Comment: @DharmeshKheni hi just put a breakpoint, Its between completedArray[0] = b1 and completedArray[1] = b2 :/

Comment: You need to debug that because as your error said you are trying to access index from array which it doesn't contain. @nar0909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either initialize the array with the necessary number of elements or append to the array.

Array Initialization:

```
let completedArray = [UInt8](count: 4)   
completedArray[0] = b1
...
```

Append:

```
let completedArray = [UInt8]()
completedArray.append(b1)
...
```

Comment: @jacket thanks for your response , yes I see the problem now :)